# How to test an SQL statement without executing it

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a SQL statement in a string, and I want to try it but without being executed.
In other words, I want to ensure that when executed later in my database return something, even a null.
SQL statements to try are queries (select). I'm using PHP with postgresql.

Comment: So why you cant't execute a query and see if it works? It's like - I can't open my eyes but I want to see.

Comment: Yes, it's not like its an update or insert.  What's the harm in running it?

Comment: Even if you test it now, you cannot -- in general -- be sure it will return something later. Result sets can depend on the time of execution, on changes in the database between now and then, ...

Comment: I understand, you are right, excuse me

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: All the better ...

Answer (score 4):

`explain` is used to show the execution plan. When issued without the `analyze` option it will not be executed:

```
=> explain select 1;
                QUERY PLAN                
------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)
(1 row)

=> explain select x;
ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
LINE 1: explain select x;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html